# "Transport endpoint is not connected" after a few seconds?

Tags: raspbian, mount, samba, ntfs, fuses

I set up a RPi as a SMB server with the official Raspbian jessie image (**not lite**). I installed `samba` and `ntfs-3g` for this purpose. The problem is whenever I start or reboot the RPi, after a few seconds all operations give the error "Transport endpoint is not connected". Remounting the filesystem (fuseblk) once may not solve the problem, but often requires remounting multiple times. So is there any workaround?

/etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt/share ntfs-3g rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,defaults,umask=000 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/dev/sda1 /media/share ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

And of course before (if you don't want to reboot):

```
mount /dev/sda1 /media/share
```

Comment: No avail. Another remount is still required before the "Transport endpoint" error message is gone.